# How can set dynamic font-family for a class in scss?

Tags: css, sass

I have a paragraph that includes english and non-english sentences. I'd like to define a class that has the ability to distinguish words language and set proper font-family.Also, I am looking for to implement this class in scss.
Is it possible to do it?

Comment: CSS can't do this on it's own. You can add spans with classes or `lang` attributes to make this happen in the markup. Then you would just apply the fonts to those styles.